# Is it possible to detect facebook/gmail banner/alerts notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to detect facebook/gmail banner/alerts notifications within our app. So if I got a facebook notification, is there a method that gets called within my app? or is there no way to detect it?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, all apps run within their own sandboxes and cannot access these types of things from other apps.

Comment: I think you meant _fortunately_.  :-)